How actually C++ strcat() works?
I have a hard time to use strcat() adding a char to char array,  I tried below
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char myStr[20] = "";
  const char a = 'T';
  const char b = 'H';
  strcat(myStr, &a);
  strcat(myStr, &b);
  strcat(myStr, "\0");
  cout << myStr;
  return 0;
}

and expect to see output "TH", however, the actual output is "THHTH".
Then I tried below code
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char myStr[20] = "";
  const char a = 'T';
  const char b = 'H';
  strcat(myStr, &a);
  strcat(myStr, &b);
//  strcat(myStr, "\0");
  cout << myStr <<'\0';
  return 0;
}

the output become "THH".
I don't understand why the output is not what I expected -- "TH".
Please any help will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you in advance.

strcat(myStr, &a); is undefined behavior. The second parameter is supposed to be a pointer null terminated string not a pointer to single character. See the documentation here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strcat

For c++ you should learn how strcat works but you will almost never want to use it in c++ code. I haven't used it in more than 20 years of my professional c++ development. Instead c++ has std::string

Both arguments of strcat() must be a pointer to (the first character of) a nul (zero) terminated array.    Furthermore, the array passed as the first argument must have enough elements to handle the second argument being appended (plus trailing nul terminator).  If any of these requirements are not met, behaviour is undefined (and no diagnostic is required).   &a and &b in your code are pointers to single characters, which are NOT elements of arrays - so the behaviour of your code is undefined.

Note that your use of strcat and "C" style character arrays in C++ indicates that you are learning C++ from an outdated source (or you have a teacher that failed to catch up on C++ since 1998). In C++ you should use std::string (and operator +=) or calls like std::format to concatenate strings.  Mostly to avoid issues like the ones you are facing here. So who or what is teaching you to write code like this? (They really should be watching this CppCon 2015: Kate Gregory “Stop Teaching C")

When dealing with C strings it's important to understand that a char array is not a valid string unless it is null-terminated.
Just getting a pointer to a char with & does not mean a zero byte follows that char in memory, and thus it is not a null-terminated string. Using a function like strcat with such a pointer results in undefined behavior.
Per the documentation for strcat at cppreference.com:

The behavior is undefined if the destination array is not large enough for the contents of both src and dest and the terminating null character. The behavior is undefined if the strings overlap. The behavior is undefined if either dest or src is not a pointer to a null-terminated byte string.

(Emphasis added by me.)

Thank you for the good explanation.  I understand now where those undefined behaviors come from...About a char array vs a C string, as long as the char array was initiated with a string such as array[] = "",  then the array will become a valid string.  Am I right? @Chris

Keep in mind that if you don't specify the dimensions of the array, your compiler will figure it out for you based on initialization. If you're initializing with an empty string literal you get an array that can hold a single character, which is useless as a string.

Thank those who answer the question, very helpful.
Like what Peter said, the strcat() requires both arguments to be char array (aka string). my code finally works with strncat() as below.
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  char myStr[20] = "";
  char a = '\T';
  char b = '\H';
  strncat(myStr, &a, 1);
  strncat(myStr, &b, 1);
  cout << myStr;
return 0;
}

For those who recommend  std::string, that was my first thought, however, I am working in Arduino environment where usually comes with a concern of heap fragmentation. That is why I choose char array to handle string.
Thank you all.

Concerns of heap fragmentation with std::string can be mitigated by using the reserve() member function (to allocate a string size that is equal to [or exceeds] the maximum anticipated string size).   Since, in shown code, you are appending exactly two characters, that is a viable option  (if appending to a std::string was done often enough to cause a problem with memory fragmentation, your approach would be hampered just as much by difficulty in sensibly setting an upper bound for array size).

@Peter.  Thank you so much. I will try string with reserve(). BTW, Arduino has similar thing to std::string called String. but I am not sure if its function and compiler also add null-terminator auotmatically like C string or requiring coder to take care of it?  In another word, does Serial.print("A") really send char '\A' + '\0'  or just '\A' over serial hardware?

My understanding (although I suggest you check) is that Arduino's string is nul terminated.   Practically String is a poor-man's equivalent of std::string (i.e. it's something provided when std::string isn't available, is less capable) Serial.print("A") would not send '\A', it would send the character 'A' (which is a different thing).    Serial device I/O (on most systems, not only arduino) does not generally send nul characters - when outputting a nul terminated string, it would normally work by outputting all characters that precede the nul, but not sending the nul.

@Peter. Thank you, I will check it out. All I need for string is to communicate with PC app via serial port/USB, the String may be just good enough which will save some flash memory (without #include ).
